# Why do order details show a critical error after checkout in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

my WordPress website order details show a critical error after checkout. May I know how to solve it? Anyone have this issue before?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPwJt.png)

Comment: There is a PHP issue - you need to check the server error_log which will tell you the exact issue. Paste it here and we can have a look at it.

Comment: 2022-10-06 11:29:44.228312 [INFO] [9768] [T0] [174.202.1.180:12545:HTTP2-3#APVH_xxx.com:443] File not found [/home/xxx/public_html/403.shtml]

Comment: That's not the PHP error log, if you can FTP or access via File Manager, go to /home/xxx/logs and there should be an error log for your site, if not in there then it will be in /home/xxx/public_html/error_log

Comment: I got it. The error log is very long. How do I post here?

Comment: Just post the last entry, that should be the PHP error that has led to your warning - Edit your question and put it in there

Comment: [06-Oct-2022 14:06:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_filter(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in /home/fengsh14/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php:174

Comment: thrown in /home/fengsh14/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php on line 174

Comment: [06-Oct-2022 14:06:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for /home/fengsh14/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpo/images/wpo_logo_small.png.webp.lossy.webp in /home/fengsh14/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-optimize/vendor/rosell-dk/webp-convert/src/Convert/Converters/AbstractConverter.php on line 216